# Can Source Generator created files be physically reached?

Tags: c#, csharp-source-generator

Is there any standard method/option, how to arrange the files generated via `Source Generators` and added to the build process are also physically visible in the project structure (so developer can review the result code e.g. via VS solution explorer window)?

I mean other than I save the code directly to a file in the generator's `Execute()`, which I would expect might bring other complications (not tried yet).

EDIT:

- According to this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49249#issuecomment-809807528, no I/O is allowed within generator execution.
- According to debug session (entering the generated code function), the generated source is at least available in the temp folder, like `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\.vsdbgsrc\some-guid\FileNameHint.cs`. Unfortunately standard VS navigation (F12) does not work (regardless of debug session activity).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add following to the project using the generator:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>DesiredPathForGeneratedStuff</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, was searching for a way to bring back the `*.razor.g.cs` files in .NET 6

Comment: Note: It seems that if you specify only the first tag, then `CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath` defaults to something like `$(IntermediateOutputPath)/generated`, for example `obj/Debug/generated`.